# How to configure Visual Studio 2019 to store IIS Express metadata (applicationhost.config) file in the same location as Visual Studio 2017 does?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, iis-express

Does anyone knows if it is possible to configure Visual Studio 2019 to store IIS Express metadata in the same location as Visual Studio 2017?

Below are the default locations where each Visual Studio version stores IIS Express metadata:

- Visual Studio 2017 - `$(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config`
- Visual Studio 2019 - `$(solutionDir)\.vs\{projectName}\config\applicationhost.config`

What I want is Visual Studio 2019 to store the metadata in `$(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` (the same way as Visual Studio 2017).

**Some context:**

- Our development team uses Visual Studio 2017.
- We have some logic (scripts & VS extensions) that customize `$(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` file to keep consistency across the (large) team.
- Some developers start moving to Visual Studio 2019 and all our logic that customizes IIS Express configuration doesn't work for them.
- We hope to find a way to configure Visual Studio 2019 to behave as Visual Studio 2017 in regard to `applicationhost.config`, file rather than changing our customization logic.